# Adding a new column, in pandas, derived from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column named 'NormalizedAnnualCompensation' derived from another 2 columns (CompTotal and CompFreq).
Here is my code:

```
for compensation in df['CompFreq']:
  if compensation == 'Yearly':
    df['NormalizeAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']
  elif compensation == 'Monthly':
    df['NormalizeAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']* 12.0
  elif compensation == 'Weekly':
    df['NormalizeAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal'] * 52.0
```

And the output

[image: output]

As you can notice, the output isn't correct, because it's simple a straight up copy from the column CompTotal. How can I fix this?

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because you overwrite the entire new column at every iteration of the loop. Apparently the last value in `df['CompFreq']` is `'Yearly'`, then the following line fills the entire new column: `df['NormalizeAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df['NormalizeAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal'] * df['CompFreq'].map({'Yearly': 1.0, 'Monthly': 12.0, 'Weekly': 52.0})
```